# Error using RxODE after updating R

Tags: r, package

> Error in rxCompile.character(.model, .mdir, extraC = .extraC, debug = .debug,  : 
>     Error loading model.

RxODE worked seamlessly before updating R.

I'd appreciate any help

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: It's a fairly common occurrence that a major update to R will break previous version of packages. Tou get specific help we need the identity of you OS and version numbers of R and your package(s). The `sessionInfo()` function is often useful in producing that information.

Answer (score 0):

As a stab in the dark, first try this:

```
 update.packages("RxODE", checkBuilt=TRUE, dependencies=TRUE)
```

The `checkBuilt` parameter is designed for use with major version changes. If this fails to correct the problem then follow through with the other more general advice in my comment above.